# What can I use instead of EventEmitter in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native. And I was playing around creating a js class where I want to support events so other systems can subscribe. I tried using EventEmitter but I noticed it is not exported in react-native 0.64, so I'm curiuous what else can I use to achive this.

```js
class FMyEventClass{
  constructor() {
    this.FMyEvent = new EventEmitter();
    setTimeout(this.Foo, 5000);
  }

  OnMyEvent(MyEventHandler) {
    return this.FMyEvent.addListener('MyEvent', MyEventHandler);
  }

  Foo() {
    this.FMyEvent.emit('MyEvent', { NewState: EAppLoginState.Register });
  }
}
```

Comment: Any luck with this so far? I'm looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

I could get it working temporarily using this:

`const EventEmitter = require('../../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/_EventEmitter');`

Im sure this is not the right way to achieve, but it works if you want to test.

Another resource to look at: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#sending-events-to-javascript